# How do I specify the cursor for this disabled WPF scrollbar?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

Summary: I would like to specify the cursor used over the ScrollViewer's disabled scrollbar.

Paste this into Kaxaml and move the mouse over the disabled vertical scrollbar. Notice that it's using the Cross cursor I specified for the ScrollViewer. Contrast this with the arrow cursor used on the enabled horizontal scrollbar.

I don't want the Cross to show over the disabled vertical scrollbar as it would imply that a particular action is possible when it's not (this is just an example, my app uses different cursors). I would prefer the arrow; can anyone tell me how to accomplish this?

```
<Page
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">  
    <ScrollViewer Height="300" Width="300" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
Cursor="Cross">
      <Canvas Width="2000">
        <Button Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="5">Left</Button>
        <Button Canvas.Left="1900" Canvas.Top="5">Right</Button>
      </Canvas>
    </ScrollViewer>
  </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the `Cursor` at the `ScrollBar` level, possibly even a lower level if you want individual buttons on the scroll bar to have different cursors. Unfortunately, the cursor for ScrollBars is hard-coded by the ScrollViewer template, so you will need to re-template it.

Here's a simple example (updated after comments):

```
<Window x:Class="SO8067799.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                        <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="Corner" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" CanHorizontallyScroll="False" CanVerticallyScroll="False" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="0" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="0"/>
                            <Grid x:Name="verticalGrid" Grid.Column="1" Cursor="Hand">
                                <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VerticalScrollBar"  Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Minimum="0" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid x:Name="horizontalGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Cursor="Hand">
                                <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="HorizontalScrollBar" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Minimum="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger SourceName="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="verticalGrid" Property="Cursor" Value="No"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger SourceName="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="horizontalGrid" Property="Cursor" Value="No"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <ScrollViewer Height="300" Width="300" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <Canvas Width="2000">
                <Button Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="5">Left</Button>
                <Button Canvas.Left="1900" Canvas.Top="5">Right</Button>
            </Canvas>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: I suspected I might need to style/template it but this code seems to have the same issue as mine. I pasted it into a simple C# WPF app and set Cursor="No" in the ScrollViewer and it has the same undesirable behavior.  I'm beginning to suspect that I'll need to subclass and handle the QueryCursor event.

Comment: The grid within the ScrollViewer seems to prevent the QueryCursor from reaching the disabled scrollbar. If I implement QueryCursor for the grid and set e.Handled = True, it behaves the way I'd like. Sure seems like a hack though. I'll mark this as the answer as it led me down a successful path. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hmm, odd. I wonder whether `ScrollViewer` sets `ForceCursor` to `true`. That's about the only explanation that makes sense to me, but I'm not on a Windows box to verify.

Comment: More info. I see that disabled controls are completely ignored in the Mouse.QueryCursor sequence. ex. Create a disabled button with Cursor="Hand" on a surface with Cursor="Cross" and it'll be a Cross over the button. If the button is enabled, it'll be the Hand. Looks like a WPF behavior.

Comment: That kind of makes sense, although I haven't seen this behavior documented anywhere. Given this behavior, it's easy enough to "trick" WPF into the result you're after by wrapping the `ScrollBar`s in a container that doesn't disable when its `ScrollBar` does. Then trigger the cursor change on the container rather than the `ScrollBar` itself. See my updated answer.

Comment: Nicely done! That's better than what I came up with. Thanks Kent!